# Enum XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to post the request to Asp.Net Web MVC using xml request content-type.
In server, I have enum object like this:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = DomainObject.SchemaNamespaceJuly2010)]
    [Serializable]
    public enum SampleTypes
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Invalid = 0,

        [EnumMember]
        Manual = 1,

        [EnumMember]
        Automated = 2
    }
```

If I send request with enum content `<SampleTypes>Manual</SampleTypes>`, it works fine, but if I use the value of enum type like `<SampleTypes>1</SampleTypes>`, It has errors:

> Invalid enum value '1' cannot be deserialized into type 'SampleTypes'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute

So I change the code to use [EnumMember(Value="")], for example:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = DomainObject.SchemaNamespaceJuly2010)]
    [Serializable]
    public enum SampleTypes
    {
        [EnumMember(Value="0")]
        Invalid = 0,

        [EnumMember(Value="1")]
        Manual = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value="2")]
        Automated = 2
    }
```

Then the enum content with `<SampleTypes>1</SampleTypes>` work fine, but the other will have error.

So my question is any idea to help both way work fines? Thanks!

By the way, For the xml serialization, I use DataContractSerializer, code example:

```
var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
return (T)deserializer.ReadObject(serialData);
```